# i was doin program of file handling,what is this issue with my vs code , im using mac os

Tags: compiler-errors, include

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FOFy.png)

i was trying to run this code: it is showing this in the output screen

aadarshchand@aadarshs-MacBook-Air file % cd "/Users/aadarshchand/Desktop/C PROGRAM/file handling/file/" && gcc file.c -o file && "/Users/aa
darshchand/Desktop/C PROGRAM/file handling/file/"file
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
aadarshchand@aadarshs-MacBook-Air file %

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
    FILE *fp ;
    char ch ;
    int no ;
    int n ;
    fp = fopen("gehu.txt", "w");
    if (fp==NULL)
    {
        printf("file can't be created");

    } 
    else 
    {
        while(k<=10)
        {
           printf("enter a no.");
           scanf("%d" ,&no);
           putw(no ,fp);
           k++;

         }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    printf("\n entered data : \n");

    fp = fopen("gehu.txt","r");
    if (fp == NULL)
    printf("file not found");
    else 
    {
        while (k<=10)
        {
           n = getw(fp);

           printf("%d", n);
           k++;
       
        }
    }


    return 0 ;
}
```